# Python OpenCV has a problem with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

**System information (version)**

- OpenCV => 4.4.0.44
- Operating System / Platform => Ubuntu 18.04.5
- Compiler => Visual Studio Code

**Detailed description**

When I import matplotlib.pyplot and uses cv2.imshow the window will just close on any key I press except for spacebar and Esc. The following code will not run but it returns no error, it simply stop running. It started after I upgrade my opencv from 4.2 to 4.4. I had tried to import matplotlib only and other matplotlib modules and they does not cause any problem.

Matplotlib version 3.3.2

**Steps to reproduce**

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video/7.mp4")
while True:
    (ret, frame) = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("Processed Output", frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
print("End")
```

Comment: Since you are reading from a video, what happens if `frame` is empty, e.g. `cap.read()` fails or at the end  of the video?

Comment: It will work perfectly End will be printed

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for it. It appears the problem iswith PyQt5 and OpenCV Qt5 when used together You can read more about the problems [here](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/386). To solve the problem you need to import `matplotlib` as below.

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```